# Why is this Perl IO code not working?

Tags: perl

Why does this code not work:

```
my $file_handle = $cgi->upload('file');
open my $OUTFILE_FOTO, '>>', "image/$new_file.$extension";
while (<$file_handle>) {
    print OUTFILE_FOTO $_;
}
close($file_handle);
close(OUTFILE_FOTO);
```

but this code does work:

```
my $file_handle = $cgi->upload('file');
open( OUTFILE_FOTO, '>>', "image/$new_file.$extension" );
while (<$file_handle>) {
    print OUTFILE_FOTO $_;
}
close($file_handle);
close(OUTFILE_FOTO);
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you're declaring and assigning a scalar `$OUTFILE_FOTO`, but you're referring to it later as if it were a bareword `OUTFILE_FOTO`.  Prepend a `$` to it in the`print` and the `close`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work now . You have created a file handle variable when you see my $OUTFILE_FOTO and this is one of the way to implement perl best practises. But you have provided Bareword - OUTFILE_FOTO in the program .You can try to avoid these errors by using use strict; and use warnings;

```
my $file_handle = $cgi->upload('file');
open my $OUTFILE_FOTO, '>>', "image/$new_file.$extension";
while (<$file_handle>) {
    print $OUTFILE_FOTO $_;
}
close($file_handle);
close($OUTFILE_FOTO);
```